# Using EventHandler with Entity Framework: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, events, event-handling

I am trying to update my database based on some events. Whenever A is generating an event, B will execute a DB update. I keep getting the following **exception**:

"A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use `await` to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

I understand the exception but I don't know where is it coming from and if it's related to using EventHandler.

After long searches:

- I made sure everything has await to make sure there is no parallel calls with the dbcontext
- I made sure I only have ONE event subscribed (this was an advice from other stackoverflow questions)
- I subscribed the event with `async/await`
- I tried `Task.WaitAll()` in all possible combinations

```
class A {
    public event EventHandler<LogArgs> LogEvent;


    public void WorkInA() {
        .....
        this.SendLogEvent();
        .....
        this.SendLogEvent();
        .....
    }

    private void SendLogEvent() {
        this.LogEvent(this, args);
    }

}
```

```
class B {
    private A a;

    public async void Init() {
        //Before: a.LogEvent += LogEventToDB;
        a.LogEvent += async (s, e) => await LogEventToDB(s, e);

    }

    public void DoWork() {
        .....
        a.WorkInA();
        .....
    }


    private async Task LogEventToDB(object sender, LogMessageEventArgs e) {
        .....
        await this.unitOfWork.SaveAsync();
        .....
    }
}
```

```
//Inside unitOfWork
public async Task SaveAsync()
{
       await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I would like to know what causes this issue and if it's possible to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your problem is due to event handling. More specifically, it's due to `async void`. **Both** of the lines of code below fall into the `async void` trap:

```
//Before: a.LogEvent += LogEventToDB;
a.LogEvent += async (s, e) => await LogEventToDB(s, e);
```

One of the [problems with `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) is that the calling code cannot know when it has completed.

If you really want to use events for log messages (which seems a bit odd to me), then you must have the events just add the log message into a queue (synchronously), and have a separate "worker" pulling messages out of the queue and sending them to the database (asynchronously).

Comment: The problem is that class A is part of a library that sends me events and I have to update the db as soon as I get the events. I also thought about the queue but if I do this, I will have to wait until the events ended right? Because if not, I will have the same issue. I also tried to make LogEventToDB return Task but that is not working either.

Comment: Your event handler can just add to the queue and then return. Since your event processor is the one writing to the db, it is the only thing that must run one-at-a-time.

Comment: I tried to use the queue but now I run into a different issue: The connection is already in a transaction and cannot participate in another transaction. EntityClient does not support parallel transactions. I do have other db operations after my queue is processing all the events. And I also await on the consumerTask.

Comment: @green: In that case, you'll need to coordinate between your queue worker and other parts of the code. Since you have that event in the middle that can't be avoided, the best solution is to either have a separate context for the log writes, or to use a shared `SemaphoreSlim` to ensure exclusive access.

Comment: The solution with separate context is referring to another DbContext? But how is it possible that if I await/Wait on the consumerTask, the next operation is being processed. Is there any way to wait for that task to be completed without doing further operations? I thought await is the way to go. Is using the barrier also an option?

Comment: "how is it possible that if I await/Wait on the consumerTask, the next operation is being processed" - because of the event. Events prevent `await` from working as desired. "Is there any way to wait for that task to be completed without doing further operations?" - Yes; you can create a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and pass it in as part of the log message, and have the handler set it when that log message has been written. I recommended the `SemaphoreSlim` approach since I think it would be easier, but either approach would work.

Comment: I will try the SemaphoreSlim then. In this case, I assume that the queue is not gonna be needed anymore because it's initial purpose was to overcome the await issue of the EventHandler.

Comment: No, you'd still need the queue. The events are still there and are still fire-and-forget, like all other events. The `SemaphoreSlim` is just allowing you to coordinate different parts of the code using the same db context.